# Prepend header record (or a string / a file) to large file in Scala / Java

Tags: scala, io, prepend

What is the most efficient (or recommended) way to prepend a string or a file to another large file in Scala, preferably without using external libraries? The large file can be binary.

E.g.

if prepend string is:
`header_information|123.45|xyz\n`

and large file is:

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789
...
```

I would expect to get:

```
header_information|123.45|xyz
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789
...
```

Comment: Why not plain unix?

Comment: @erip Because in this case it will be workaround and second it will not necessarily always be unix filesystem,  it can be AWS S3 or something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I come up with the following solution:

1. Turn prepend string/file into InputStream
2. Turn large file into InputStream
3. "Combine" InputStreams together using java.io.**SequenceInputStream**
4. Use java.nio.file.**Files.copy** to write to target file

   ```
   object FileAppender {
     def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
       val stringToPrepend = new ByteArrayInputStream("header_information|123.45|xyz\n".getBytes)
       val largeFile = new FileInputStream("big_file.dat")
       Files.copy(
         new SequenceInputStream(stringToPrepend, largeFile),
         Paths.get("output_file.dat"),
         StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING
       )
     }
   }
   ```

Tested on ~30GB file, took ~40 seconds on MacBookPro (3.3GHz/16GB).

This approach can be used (if necessary) to combine multiple partitioned files created by e.g. Spark engine.